# psexec not getting output on powershell on remote PC

Tags: powershell, psexec

### ReadPower.ps1 contain the following. And able to get output on output.csv locally.

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM7,19200,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("?p")
$port.ReadLine()
$MachinePower= $port.ReadLine()
$date = Get-Date
$TextTOsend = "MachineName,"+ $date +"," +$MachinePower
$TextTOsend | Out-File output.csv -Append -Encoding ASCII
$port.Close()
```

---

When run remotely, using this

```
psexec \\RemotePC -s -u username -p password powershell C:\ReadFAMLaser\ReadPower.ps1
```

No output on output.csv
Did I miss out anything?

Comment: Are you expecting output.csv to appear locally or on the remote PC?

Comment: I am expecting it on remote PC. Or is there a way to return a line of text from remote PC? It look like the script is able to run just not writing the result to file.

Comment: Where have you looked for it (on the remote pc)? You aren't specifying a directory so my guess is it should be in the powershell install directory.